# Filtering child item with QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: qt4, qt4.8, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm using QSortFilterProxyModel on a QTreeView, and I'm trying to filter both top level items and the first-level child items.

Is that possible? Seems like QSortFilterProxyModel only filter on top level items.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please provide more details on what you already tried? [The doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details) says **If a parent item doesn't match the filter, none of its children will be shown**, which probably explain why it seems to filter only on first level.

If your goal is to filter only specific levels of your tree, you should subclass **QSortFilterProxyModel** and reimplement the **filterAcceptRow**. This way you can specify to ignore items that do not belong to specific tree levels. See [the doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details) for more informations.